# Spring Boot ErrorPageFilter block the custom exception handler with @ExceptionHandler

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

My web app constructed with SpringBoot 2.0.0.M3 and java8, deploy on outer tomcat/8.0.24 war.
My Exception handler:

```
@ControllerAdvice(annotations = RestController.class)
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends 
ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
@ExceptionHandler(MyCustomException.class)
public ResponseEntity<String> handlerMyException(
        MyCustomException rae) {
    String msg = "MyCustomException";
    return new ResponseEntity<>(msg ,
            HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

I trow a MyCustomException in my Controller but it wasn't handled by handlerMyException() method:

```
 ERROR 1 --- [ajp-nio-8009-exec-372] o.s.b.w.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter  : Forwarding to error page from request [/api/test] due to exception
```

Then I disable the ErrorPageFilter by:

```
setRegisterErrorPageFilter(false);
```

this time no error log occurred, but handlerMyException() still not triggered. Is anyone know this? TIA!

Comment: unless you have your rest controller in some other package, this should work. Did you tried using debug or logging if you really executing you method ? Also ErrorPageFilter is trying to find correct view to display your exception.

Comment: this issue will fixed once app deploy/redeloy , and occur after period of time( few hours), I guess the root cause is that the instance of GlobalExceptionHandler somehow disappear ?